# Unable to start receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver android Oreo

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

Hello I am using GCM for push notification, i am getting lot of crashes on Android O 
`WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java line 99
android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService`

I am not using FCM for push notification, kindly help me out to fix this issue in Android O. Following is the stacktrace of the error in fabric.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.tapmad.tapmadtv cmp=com.tapmad.tapmadtv/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b7ea475 u0a216 RCVR bg:+1m30s74ms idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3399)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1780)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: show full log please

Comment: updated.. please have a look

Comment: can you show your manifest file

Comment: what part of manifest i would show you because file is too long. let me know the part

Comment: show the part which is responsible for handling notifications and gcm id and also their classes

Comment: <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.tapmad.tapmadtv" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184128/discussion-between-jhaman-das-and-har-kal).

Comment: @JhamanDas, It is saying in background service can not work as the service can work for 5 second when app is closed in Oreo. Either you use firebaes or figure out how to use service in background with notifications.